# Java: Longest Ascending substring

Tags: java, for-loop, compiler-errors, substring

I am trying to create a Java program that reads a numerical string typed from the keyboard,

and gives out the longest ascending substring.

The following is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Ascending{
public static void main(String args[]){

Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("Enter a number = ");
String n = in.nextLine(); 
int length = n.length(); 


for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {

    char first = n.charAt(i);       
    char next = n.charAt(i+1);      
    char last = n.charAt(length-1);     
    int f = (int)(first - 48);      
    int nx = (int)(next - 48);      
    int l = (int)(last - 48);       

        if (f<nx) {


        String asc = n.substring(i, i++);   
        i++;
        System.out.println("output = " + asc);
            }

        else {
            String asc = n.substring(i, i++);
            System.out.println("output = " + asc);
            break;}

        }

    }
}
```

When I compile the above, I get

```
<Enter a number = 12 output = >
```

without any results.

I am assuming something went wrong inside the for-loop but I am unable to figure out where exactly I went wrong.

I'm afraid I might have defined too many unnecessary variables?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the post-increment operator, but I don't think you have experimented to see how it works.  Try this:

```
int i = 0;

System.out.println(i);
System.out.println(i++);
System.out.println(i);
```

You'll get

```
0
0
1
```

That's because post-increment (`++`) says "increment this value, then return what the value was *before you incremented it*".

So when you ask for

```
n.substring(i, i++);
```

You are explicitly asking for a 0-length string (because `i == i++`).

You could use the pre-increment operator, `++i`, but it's rarely used outside of code-golf so you'll just end up confusing people.  Best practice IMO is to just use `++` on its own line and avoid looking at the return value.

Really, what you want here is

```
n.substring(i, i+1);
```

Comment: I would get the correct result if I do that but that is only if the input is less than 2 digits. For instance, if I wrote, '41234', I get nothing for the output again. I thought I had to get the substring of the increment to get the full '1234'. None of the (i++, ++i, i+1) seem to be working for some reason..

Comment: @BettyJones Because you have a `break` in your 'else' condition.  I sense you are coding by putting pieces of code together without understanding why.  I recommend the opposite approach: for every statement you write you should ask yourself, "why do I *need* to have this statement in here? What will go wrong if I leave it out?"  If you have something like `i++` where you want to use it but don't understand it, write a separate test program to figure out how it works.

Comment: Ok, will try to start working on it that way again. Thank you!